# Using background images in select box using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello friends i want to use images in select box like **[this](http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/)**. can i do the same using simple code like hand code using jQuery. i just want to beautify my form

Please Help

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You will soon shalt be asked questions like: **What have you tried.com **or** show me some code **or** this aint research place anyhow just informing bro; be lil elaborative, <I will not downvote> :)**

Comment: *"this aint research place anyhow just informing bro"*

Answer (score 1):

You may use Uniform plugin:
http://uniformjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

[image: image combobox v2.38]you can use this

[JavaScript image combobox v2.38](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

**[Filament Group's Select Menu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) is the business.**